# How do I display object details from the model on bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to get Album details from the model to bootstrap modal. I would like to click on the each Album and display the information related like Artist and Title for each specific Album.

As I am using Asp.net Core 2.2 I have tried to use asp-route-id="ID" to map the object but the problem is that it is displaying the all page details.

Here is my Model

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public int MusicID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Music> Music { get; set; }
}
```

Music model

```
    public class Music
{
    public int MusicID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

Details controller
    // GET: Albums/Details/5

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id) {
    if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

    var album = await _context.Albums.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlbumID == id);
    if (album == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(album);
}
```

Bellow is the bootstrap modal

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" asp-controller="Musics" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
```

Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to get details about Artist, Title and Album only, instead of all detail page.

Answer (score 1):

Dear @Rocha you are not mentioned by which method you want to get data and you are also not provide Album model properties, so here I just write json code for MVC Core by which you can get music information details and display on your bootstrap modal.

**IAction Method**

```
public IActionResult MusicDetails(int MusicID)
        {
            var varMusic = _db.Music.SingleOrDefault(aa => aa.Topicid == MusicID);
            Music obj = new Music();
            if(varMusic!=null)
            {
                obj.Artist = varMusic.Artist;
                obj.Title = varMusic.Title;
                var varAlbum = _db.Album.Where(aa => aa.Topicid == MusicID);
                List<Album> albumcollection = new List<Music>();
                foreach(var item in varAlbum)
                {
                    Album albumitem = new Album();
                    albumitem.item1 = item.item1;
                    albumitem.item2 = item.item2;
                    albumcollection.Add(albumitem);
                }
                obj.Album = albumcollection;
            }
            return Json(obj);
        }
```

**Button Html Code**

```
<button id="btn1" type="button" asp-controller="Musics" asp-action="Details" value="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Get Music Details</button>
```

**Bootstrap Modal Design**

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">Artist:</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <span id="spanArtist"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">Title:</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <span id="spanTitle"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr style="margin-bottom:0px;" />
                    <table id="tblAlbum" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:5%;">S.No.</th>
                                <th>Column1</th>
                                <th>Column2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tblalbumbody">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Json and JQuery**

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').on('click', function (e) {
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            var _MusicID = $(this).val();
            $("#tblAlbum tbody tr").remove();
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("MusicDetails")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        MusicID: _MusicID
                    },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#spanArtist').html(data.artist);
                    $('#spanTitle').html(data.title);                       

                    $.each(data.particularsList, function (i, item) {
                            var rows = "<tr>" +
                                "<td  style='text-align: center;padding:5px;'> " + item.srNo + "</td>" +
                                "<td  style='text-align: left;padding:5px;'>" + item.item1 + "</td>" +
                                "<td  style='text-align: left;padding:5px '>" + item.item2   + "</td>"
                                "</tr>";
                            $('#tblalbumbody').append(rows);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve data.' + ex);
                    }
             });
            return false;
        });
   });
    <script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have updated my question. I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ViewModel to show what you want,here is a simple demo as follow:

1.ViewModel:

```
public class ArtistViewModel
{
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public List<string> Title { get; set; }
}
```

2.Album/Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Album>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Artist)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MusicID)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var music in item.Music)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => music.MusicID)<br/>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="btn1" data-id="@item.AlbumID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="Click(@item.AlbumID)">detail</button>
            </td>
            <td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="Close()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="details">
                <table id="tblAlbum" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Artist</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tblalbumbody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="Close()">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function Click(id) {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'Details/' + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                        var rows = "<tr>" +
                        "<td  style='text-align: left;'> " + data.artist + "</td>" +
                        "<td  style='text-align: left;'>" + data.title + "</td>"
                    "</tr>";
                    $('#tblalbumbody').append(rows);                
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
                },
            });
        }
        function Close() {
            $("#tblalbumbody tr").remove();
        }
    </script>
}
```

2.AlbumsController:

```
// GET: Albums
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Album.Include(a=>a.Music).ToListAsync());
    }

 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var album = await _context.Albums
        .Include(a => a.Music).Where(a => a.AlbumID == id)
        .Select(a => new ArtistViewModel()
        {
            Artist = a.Artist,
            Title = a.Music.Select(m=>m.Title).ToList()
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (album == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return new JsonResult(album);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

1.I change the `detail` button(use `data-id` and add an onclick function)

2.Also I change two `close` button in modal(add an onclick function)

3.Change the return type.

4.Change the type of `Title`

5.Add the Index action

Comment: thanks for the help. How do I get those values into the modal for each Album in the Album Index.cshtml

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, this line  `a.Music.Select(m => m.Title).ToList() ` is giving the following error:  Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Collections.Generic.List<string>’ to ‘string’

Comment: if I change `a.Music.Select(m => m.Title).ToList()` to `a.Music.Select(m => m.Title).ToString()` the error goes away but I getting unhandled exception AspNetCore.Views_Albums_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml, line 33  in the browser. The line 33 is `@foreach (var music in item.Music)`

Comment: Hi RochaCarter07,it is my fault.I change the ViewModel but not update correctly.You need to change the `Title` property `string` to `List<string>` in ViewModel.

Comment: Hi @Rena, thanks one more time. I have change as you suggested above but I am getting this browser error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  AspNetCore.Views_Albums_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml, line 22  `@foreach (var music in item.Music)`

Comment: Hi RochaCarter07,you may miss the `include(a=>a.Music)` in your Index action.I update my code.

Comment: Hi @Rena thanks again. The modal pops up and it display the table heading but it does not pull any data from the model

Comment: Hi RochaCarter07,I think you should press F12 in the browser and check the mistake in the console.Did the url make mistake?